# Confused by official mongodb documentation, what is socketTimeoutMS?

Tags: mongodb

I found two different places with different explanation what does `socketTimeoutMS` do.

> The time in milliseconds to attempt a send or receive on a socket before the attempt times out. The default is never to timeout, though different drivers might vary. See the driver documentation.

From [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connection-string-options)

---

And following one:

> The socketTimeoutMS sets the number of milliseconds a socket stays inactive after the driver has successfully connected before closing. If the value is set to 360000 milliseconds, the socket closes if there is no activity during a 30 seconds window.

From [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/reference/faq/)

What does really `socketTimeoutMS` do?

Answer (score 0):

Due to what the docs say, it will be the functionality what the driver is providing

> See the driver documentation.

In your case if you're using nodejs (the link you sent) it will be as you quoted in your second quote

> The socketTimeoutMS sets the number of milliseconds a socket stays inactive after the driver has successfully connected before closing. If the value is set to 360000 milliseconds, the socket closes if there is no activity during a 30 seconds window.

Comment: I don't agree with you, *The default is never to timeout, though different drivers might vary.*  According to text only `socketTimeoutMS` **value** may vary from driver to driver.

Comment: In the first one, it's timeout for *send/receive* attempt, i.e. big query which takes 500ms to complete while timeout set to 300 ms will be failed. In the second one,  for *socket stays inactive*, i.e. timeout set for 10 seconds, and there wasn't any query for 20 seconds, the connection will be closed. It's my understanding of the written above.